# [ddms]: ADB rejected shell command (am get-config): closed

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I am new in React Native. When i try to build my new(empty) react native project on Android Studio. It is working. But when i try to build on Visual Studio Code Terminal as "npx react-native run-android". it gives the following error;

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
> 38 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 36 up-to-date
> [ddms]: ADB rejected shell command (am get-config): closed
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: closed

I didn't get this error. How can i solve it ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Edit: when i face this error, reset pc and error fixed temporarly. Something executing more than one .exe file at the background. What is that idk

Comment: I experience the exact same issue, did you manage to find a solution?